# Spring Boot Unsupported Media Type (415) for file uploads

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a new POST endpoint using Spring Boot using the following code:

```java
@Controller
@Path("/my")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1024*1024*1024, maxRequestSize = 1024*1024*1024)
public class MyResource {

    @POST
    @Path("parseFile")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Invalid format")})
    })
    public Response parseFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        // Use file
    }
}
```

I've added config in application.yml file:

```yaml
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 2MB
      file-size-threshold: 3MB
```

Based on the [docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.spring-mvc.multipart-file-uploads), it should automagically work and allow requests, but I'm getting the following response:

```json
{
    "timestamp": 1667463311931,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "path": "/app/api/my/parseFile"
}
```

I've also tried adding AutoConfig elements manually as well in a `@Configuration` class like:

```java
@Bean
public MultipartAutoConfiguration multipartAutoConfiguration() {
    var props = new MultipartProperties();
    props.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.ofMegabytes(10));
    props.setEnabled(true);
    return new MultipartAutoConfiguration(props);
}
```

On the server side I'm only seeing the following log:

```json
{"@timestamp":"2022-11-03T08:10:34.066Z","message":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Nov/2022:08:10:34 +0000] \"POST /app/api/my/parseFile HTTP/1.1\" 415 126 \"-\" \"PostmanRuntime/7.29.2\"","request_id":"-","local_request_id":"4f9396ff817861e9","ext":{"accessLog":true,"cloudId":"fake","host":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","method":"POST","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","statusCode":"415","requestedUri":"/app/api/my/parseFile","requestPath":"/app/api/my/parseFile","responseContentLength":"126","elapsedTimeMs":"5"}}
```

Postman Request:
[image: Postman Body]

[image]

The file type that I'm trying to upload is of type `*.ics` and is a text file.

I'm using Spring Boot version 2.5.2.

Comment: have you tried using MultipartFile[]

Comment: I only want single file uploads

Comment: add header content-type multipart form data

Im also seeing that that the api is not well written 
the api path is myparsefile
however if do you want to make it /my/parsefile  add '/' to the api path

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Just following team convention, all existing paths across the app are written like that. That header is automatically added by postman even if unchecked. I'm getting the same result with it checked and unchecked.

Comment: can you remove multipartConfig just to check ?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the media type header you send is not supported. I'm not 100% familiar `@POST` but I guess there is a possibility there as well.

In any cases, you can use Spring annotations. Change it from `@POST` and `@Path` to `@PostMapping(path = "parseFile", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })`

Comment: This also doesn't work. I also tried adding `@Consumes({"multipart/form-data"})`

Comment: Do you still get HTTP 415?

Comment: `Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided` on server side and 415 on client

Comment: I ran the debugger and added a debug point in MultipartAutoConfig methods, and it was getting hit, not sure why it still says no multipart config has been provided

Comment: There seems to be confusion between MVC Controller and REST. I think you need to change the `@Controller` to  `@RestController` and maybe also `@Path` to `@RequestMapping` at the class level.

Comment: I already have a Spring MVC controller, and want to keep using it

Comment: Then you can't test it with Postman

Answer (score 0):

change your post method to this

```
 @PostMapping(value="/parsefile", consumes ="multipart/form-data")
    public Response parseFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) 
        {
            // Use file
        }
```